# Deterministic Addition of Time + Date to DateTime

Tags: sql-server, deterministic

Attempting to add a time and date together into an indexed view, which means it has to be deterministic. My understanding was that 'convert' was deterministic...

The latest iteration I've tried is below. I've also tried just simple Covert(Datetime,Calendar_Date+HH24MISS_T) but it says 'Operand data type date is invalid for add operator.'

```
create view udm.DATETIME with schemabinding as select
  CONVERT(DATETIME,
    CONVERT(CHAR(10), CALENDAR_DATE, 23) 
    + '' '' + 
    CONVERT(CHAR(8), HH24MISS_T, 108) 
    ,120)
    as Calendar_DateTime
  from U.DateTable D;

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX DATETIME
  ON udm.DATETIME (Calendar_DateTime);

--ERROR: Column 'Calendar_DateTime' in view 'udm.DATETIME' cannot be used in an index or statistics or as a partition key because it is non-deterministic.
```

Comment: `CONVERT` is not deterministic: [Deterministic and Nondeterministic Functions: Built-in Function Determinism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/deterministic-and-nondeterministic-functions?view=sql-server-2017#built-in-function-determinism). What are the data types for `CALENDAR_DATE` and `HH24MISS_T`?

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this in the database in the first place. Datetime data should stay in the appropriate datatype. Then do display formatting in the front end.

Comment: If the combination of CALENDAR_DATE and HH24MISS_T must be unique when combined, why is the combination not unique within the underlying table as separate columns? I.E., why not simply create a unique constraint on (CALENDATE_DATE, HH24MISS_T)?

Comment: @Larnu: CALENDAR_DATE is date, HH24MISS_T is time, trying to combine into a single datetime data type. As the link you sent mentions, convert is deterministic when used with non-deterministic style parameters when converting to/from varchar/datetime.

Comment: @SMor I cut out some stuff to make it easier to see here, but the date is technically from  one table and the time another. UDM.datetable is your basic calendar table that just has a record for every day in it, and the time table has a record for every milisecond. What I'm doing is building a sort of hourly combination of the two because we are tracking some KPIs by hour, so I filtered the dates to relevant dates and filtered all the milisecond stuff out so it's just the hourly 'times'. Next step i'll join to the KPI by hr data.

Comment: @SeanLange I'm basically creating aggregate indexed views of an hourly KPI for performance. See response to SMOR, but I'm joining on a KPI that has a datetime rounded to the nearest hour, so I'm wanting a this Calendar_DateTime to join on that.